# Printing Python Key elements by Value in List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

I have a question that I think is fairly simple but I can't figure out the syntax to.

I have a list of dictionaries which looks like this:

```
[{'word': 'the', 'count': 19}, 
 {'word': 'and', 'count': 14}, 
 {'word': 'he', 'count': 7}, 
 {'word': 'left', 'count': 1}, 
 {'word': 'dead', 'count': 1}, 
 {'word': 'its', 'count': 1}, 
 {'word': 'head', 'count': 1}, 
 {'word': 'galumphing', 'count': 1}, 
 {'word': 'arm', 'count': 1}, 
 {'word': 'beamish', 'count': 1}, 
 {'word': 'boy', 'count': 1}, 
 {'word': 'o', 'count': 1}]
```

I simply want a for loop which accesses the count variable and prints every dictionary where count = 1. The output I'm looking for:

```
[{'word': 'left', 'count': 1}, 
 {'word': 'dead', 'count': 1}, 
 {'word': 'its', 'count': 1}, 
 {'word': 'head', 'count': 1}, 
 {'word': 'galumphing', 'count': 1}, 
 {'word': 'arm', 'count': 1}, 
 {'word': 'beamish', 'count': 1}, 
 {'word': 'boy', 'count': 1}, 
 {'word': 'o', 'count': 1}]
```

What would be the easiest way to achieve something like this! Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can Just Make a List Variable And `if` the `dict`s `count` key has value `1`, `append` the `dict` to the List Variable!

As Shown Here!

Code:

```
result = []
list_of_dict = [{'word': 'the', 'count': 19},
 {'word': 'and', 'count': 14},
 {'word': 'he', 'count': 7},
 {'word': 'left', 'count': 1},
 {'word': 'dead', 'count': 1},
 {'word': 'its', 'count': 1},
 {'word': 'head', 'count': 1},
 {'word': 'galumphing', 'count': 1},
 {'word': 'arm', 'count': 1},
 {'word': 'beamish', 'count': 1},
 {'word': 'boy', 'count': 1},
 {'word': 'o', 'count': 1}]
for i in list_of_dict:
    if i["count"] == 1:
      result.append(i)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
    [{'word': 'left', 'count': 1}, 
     {'word': 'dead', 'count': 1}, 
     {'word': 'its', 'count': 1}, 
     {'word': 'head', 'count': 1}, 
     {'word': 'galumphing', 'count': 1}, 
     {'word': 'arm', 'count': 1}, 
     {'word': 'beamish', 'count': 1}, 
     {'word': 'boy', 'count': 1}, 
     {'word': 'o', 'count': 1}]
```

Its The Simplest Way To Do It

Comment: The Pythonic way to do this is with a simple list comprehension.    It's more compact, more efficient, and clearer.  See my answer for preferred way to do it.

Comment: Yep I could Do That Also! Thanks! Its Fast and Short, In 1 Line! But I just Edited The Existing Code in To a Simple and Easy Thing! Which is Easy to Understand And Resolve with out changing much Code! Your Answer is Nice Though!

Answer (score 2):

I worked out a solution to this problem myself shortly after posting the question. The easiest way to do it is this:

```
for x in array:
    if x['count'] == 1:
    print(x)
```

This prints the values where the specific count equals 1!

Comment: you better change variable name `list` to anything else. As it is not good practice to use reserved keys.

Comment: yeah just changed that now

Comment: If all you want to do is print the desired list elements, then this is a good way to do it.  But that wasn't the question.  The question requested that a list of the desired elements be created (since the sample output was enclosed in `[]`).  So this doesn't solve the problem posed by the question.  The preferred way to generate a list of the desired elements is to use a list comprehension, as shown in my answer (which answers the posted question).

Answer (score 2):

The preferred, Pythonic way to do this is with a list comprehension.  This is clearer, more compact, and more efficient than appending to a list from within a loop.

If you have:

```
lst = [{'word': 'the', 'count': 19},
       {'word': 'and', 'count': 14},
       {'word': 'he', 'count': 7},
       {'word': 'left', 'count': 1},
       {'word': 'dead', 'count': 1},
       {'word': 'its', 'count': 1},
       {'word': 'head', 'count': 1},
       {'word': 'galumphing', 'count': 1},
       {'word': 'arm', 'count': 1},
       {'word': 'beamish', 'count': 1},
       {'word': 'boy', 'count': 1},
       {'word': 'o', 'count': 1}]
```

You can do:

```
lst2 = [d for d in lst if d['count'] == 1]
```

This sets `lst2` to:

```
[{'word': 'left', 'count': 1},
 {'word': 'dead', 'count': 1},
 {'word': 'its', 'count': 1},
 {'word': 'head', 'count': 1},
 {'word': 'galumphing', 'count': 1},
 {'word': 'arm', 'count': 1},
 {'word': 'beamish', 'count': 1},
 {'word': 'boy', 'count': 1},
 {'word': 'o', 'count': 1}]
```